# How to set field select option value selected in admin form?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminform, select

i set the value for select field in admin form like this

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('test_yeezy/test')->getCollection();
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
          $values[] = array(
                        'value'     => $category->getCategoryId(),
                        'label'     => $category->getCategoryName()
                      );
        }

$fieldset->addField(
            'attribute_magento',
            'select',
            array(
                'name'   => 'attribute_magento0',
                'container_id' => 'attribute-magento0',
                'values' => $values,
        ));
```

the first value selected always the first record of the data, is there anyway to make the value selected first if it's not the first data, for example in html goes like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw" selected>VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Try adding `'value'   => 'vw'` after `values => $values` in your code. This should make VW default selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, try this way:

Adding `'value' => 'vw'` after `'values' => $values` in your `addField`

```
$fieldset->addField(
        'attribute_magento',
        'select',
        array(
            'name'   => 'attribute_magento0',
            'container_id' => 'attribute-magento0',
            'values' => $values,
            'value' => 'vw',
    ));
```